# Get a django instance that is selected with the mouse

Tags: django

I define in django a class called Scenario. The view of Scenario is this:
[image]

If you want to use the button called "Check Issues", you have to click with your mouse on one scenario, in this case you only can click on "s1" or "s2".

The button call a python function called gen_issues, here is the code:

```
class ScenarioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/button.html'
    ...

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            django.urls.path('issue/', self.gen_issues),
            django.urls.path('duplicate/', self.gen_duplicate),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def gen_issues(self, request):
        if len(request.user.username) > 0:
            queryset=super().get_queryset(request)
            #scenarios = Scenario.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
            if len(queryset) == 1:
                sv = ScenarioVerifier(queryset[0])
                sv.verify()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("../")
            else:
                self.message_user(request,len(queryset) ,level=messages.ERROR)
                return HttpResponseRedirect("../")
```

But It doesn't work because I don't know how to get the clicked scenario, so the queryset in the function "gen_issues" is wrong beacuse it has two elements, i.e, all the scenarios, not the selected  with the mouse.

So my question is how can get the selected scenario with the mouse in order to can use it inside my function.

In other words, the next sentence in my function is worng

```
queryset=super().get_queryset(request)
```

What would be the correct sentence in order to filter the scenario clicked with the mouse??

Comment: Can you rework your solution to use the django admin [actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#adding-actions-to-the-modeladmin)?

Comment: @schillingt But the django admin actions have to be writte outside the class ScenarioAdmin. In that case , the code is called by a button, and for this reason, I have to write the function inside of class ScenarioAdmin

Comment: You can override template

Comment: @schillingt do you know the correct sentence in order to filter the scenario clicked with the mouse? Because queryset =super().get_queryset(request) is wrong.

Comment: `super` is used for inhertiance. You'd use that to call `super().gen_issues`. If you want to access the ModelAdmin's `get_queryset` method, you'd use `self.get_queryset(request)`

Comment: @schillingt The sentence self.get_queryset(request) takes all the instances, not only the selected with the mouse.

Comment: @schillingt I have to do something like this example with Hero class: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/action_buttons.html but not for all heros, only one selected with the mouse in the panel